# NGINX select a subfolder under the root dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I need nginx to select a subfolder under the root folder dynamically for every request based on the first segment of the path in the URL, returning 404 if the subfolder doesn't exist. This should be made without using multiple locations.

For example, this is the directory structure on the server:

- /services/a
- /services/b

The url http://server/**a**/app.php would call app.php under the /services/a directory.

The url http://server/**b**/app.php would call app.php under the /services/b directory.

Here is the standard nginx config for Symfony which I need to modify:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    root /services;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /${NGINX_ENTRY_POINT}$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Just remove the `^` from the `location` regular expression, and they will match `/anything/app.php` instead of just `/app.php`

Comment: Also this would only work if your apps expects to run from a baseurl. so they should not have a problem when the url has a `/a/`